# Expanding a variable within a protected label

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I have some trouble with expanding variables within a protected label.
I need a automatisated caption with a label all inside a command. Within the caption I want to have a two digit number (padzeroes). For this I have to use a temporary variable.

```
\newcommand{\Spezifikation}[5]{ %
\setcounter{tmpa}{#2}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.85\linewidth}
\captionof{spezifikation}{S\textunderscore#1
        \hspace{-1.5ex}
        \textunderscore\hspace{-0.85ex}\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{tmpa}}}
\protect\label{spec: #5}
\end{minipage}
}
```

That is the part in the .aux file:

```
test.aux:\@writefile{lspec}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lspec}{\contentsline {spezifikation}{\numberline {}{\ignorespaces S\textunderscore SYS \hspace  {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace  {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\@decimal {1}}\relax }}{11}{spezifikation.1}}
test.aux:\newlabel{spec: SYS-Modularisierung}{{1}{11}{S\textunderscore SYS \hspace {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}\relax \relax }{spezifikation.1}{}}
```

And the .lspec file

```
test.lspec:\contentsline {spezifikation}{\numberline {}{\ignorespaces S\textunderscore SYS \hspace {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\@decimal {1}}\relax }}{11}{spezifikation.1}
```

I think, the problem is the expanding of `tmpa` at `test.aux:\newlabel{...`
At the other lines it was well expanded to the number behind.

How can I fix it?

---

Addition 1:

If I change

```
\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}
```

to

```
\padzeroes[2]{\decimalnum{#2}}
```

I got this error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted
```

Normally it goes. But ot in this case (in a caption). I don't understand why.

---

Addition 2

Here comes a short executable:

```
\documentclass[,12pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn,notitlepage]{article} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=40mm, outer=20mm,
            top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
            headheight=15mm, headsep=7mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through textcomp 
\usepackage{verbatim, environ}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{newfloat,tocloft,caption,multicol,suffix,fmtcount,nameref}
\newcounter{tmpa}


\newcommand{\Spezifikation}[5]{ %
\setcounter{tmpa}{#2}
%
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\linewidth}
\vspace*{0.7ex}
\captionof{spezifikation}{S\textunderscore#1
        \hspace{-1.5ex}
        \textunderscore\hspace{-0.85ex}\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{tmpa}}}
\protect\label{spec: #5}
\textit{Inhalt:} #3\\[0.5ex]
\textit{Referenz:} #4\\[0.5ex]
\textit{EOS}
\vspace{0.7ex}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}
%
% float-Object einer Spezifikation
%
%    Listenendung: lspec
%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext   = lspec, %
                            placement = h] %
                            {spezifikation}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{DCFs}{\raggedright \textit{Spec.-Nr.:} #3}
\captionsetup[spezifikation]{format = DCFs,
                             font = bf,
                             listformat = empty,
                             position = above}  

\begin{document}
\Spezifikation{hallo}{1}{Text}{Text}{Label1} 
\Spezifikation{hallo}{2}{Text}{Text}{Label2} 
\Spezifikation{hallo}{3}{Text}{Text}{Label3} 
\Spezifikation{hallo}{4}{Text}{Text}{Label4} 
\nameref{spec: Label1} 
\end{document}
```

You will see I reference to the first spec but it gives me the last. I think this is because of tmpa.
This shows the aux:

```
\@writefile{lspec}{\contentsline {spezifikation}{\numberline {}{\ignorespaces S\textunderscore hallo \hspace  {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace  {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\@decimal {1}}\relax }}{1}}
\newlabel{spec: Label1}{{1}{1}{S\textunderscore hallo \hspace {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}\relax \relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lspec}{\contentsline {spezifikation}{\numberline {}{\ignorespaces S\textunderscore hallo \hspace  {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace  {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\@decimal {2}}\relax }}{1}}
\newlabel{spec: Label2}{{2}{1}{S\textunderscore hallo \hspace {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}\relax \relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lspec}{\contentsline {spezifikation}{\numberline {}{\ignorespaces S\textunderscore hallo \hspace  {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace  {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\@decimal {3}}\relax }}{1}}
\newlabel{spec: Label3}{{3}{1}{S\textunderscore hallo \hspace {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}\relax \relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lspec}{\contentsline {spezifikation}{\numberline {}{\ignorespaces S\textunderscore hallo \hspace  {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace  {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\@decimal {4}}\relax }}{1}}
\newlabel{spec: Label4}{{4}{1}{S\textunderscore hallo \hspace {-1.5ex} \textunderscore \hspace {-0.85ex}\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}\relax \relax }{}{}}
```

The reference are right but it shows me the caption-text wrong. Because of the not expanding `tmpa` it gives me the last entry of `tmpa`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without knowing the definition of `\padzeroes` and `\decimal` it's difficult to say.

Comment: Please edit your question to be a complete small document that shows the problem, your fragments include many non standard commands such as `\decimal`  `\defcounter` etc, so we can't really even guess how they work or what the problem is.

Comment: `\padzeroes` and `\decimal` comes with the fmtcount-pacakage

Comment: [http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount/fmtcount.pdf]

Comment: @Alex44 Neither `\padzeroes` nor `\decimal` are fully expandable. If you look in the `.aux` file, you'll see that `\newlabel` has a literal `\padzeroes [2]{\decimal {tmpa}}`.

Comment: Yes. You're rigth. But one line above `tmpa` was expanded: `{\@decimal {4}}`

Comment: I think the reason for the unexpanded was `\protect\label{}`. But I have to protect the label inside the command. So I think I have to ensure that the label-arguments expandet or only tmpa before it is written to the aux-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in `\protect\label` which is not needed. The real issue is in what is written in the `.aux` file; the caption text is not expanded, so `\padzeroes[2]\decimal{tmpa}` is written as is.

You have to expand the caption text, but using `\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{tmpa}}` would prevent it anyway, because the two commands are not fully expandable.

Here's a working version:

```
\documentclass[,12pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn,notitlepage]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=40mm, outer=20mm,
            top=25mm, bottom=25mm,
            headheight=15mm, headsep=7mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through textcomp 
\usepackage{verbatim, environ}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{newfloat,tocloft,caption,multicol,suffix,fmtcount,nameref}
\newcounter{tmpa}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mypad}[1]{\two@digits{\value{#1}}}

\newcommand{\Spezifikation}[5]{%
  \setcounter{tmpa}{#2}%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.85\linewidth}
  \vspace*{0.7ex}
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \protect\captionof{spezifikation}{S\textunderscore#1%
      \textunderscore\mypad{tmpa}}}\x\label{spec: #5}
    \textit{Inhalt:} #3\\[0.5ex]
  \textit{Referenz:} #4\\[0.5ex]
  \textit{EOS}
  \vspace{0.7ex}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother
%
% float-Object einer Spezifikation
%
%    Listenendung: lspec
%
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext   = lspec, %
                            placement = h] %
                            {spezifikation}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{DCFs}{\raggedright \textit{Spec.-Nr.:} #3}
\captionsetup[spezifikation]{format = DCFs,
                             font = bf,
                             listformat = empty,
                             position = above}  

\begin{document}
\Spezifikation{hallo}{1}{Text}{Text}{Label1} 
\Spezifikation{hallo}{2}{Text}{Text}{Label2} 
\Spezifikation{hallo}{3}{Text}{Text}{Label3} 
\Spezifikation{hallo}{4}{Text}{Text}{Label4} 
\nameref{spec: Label1} 
\end{document}
```

Watch out for spurious spaces in your definitions. I removed the negative `\hspace` commands that were necessary only because of them.

---

I add an expandable padding macro; extend it if you need more than five digits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\epadzeroes}[2]{%
  \ifcase#1\or\or
    \etwo@digits{#2}\or
    \ethree@digits{#2}\or
    \efour@digits{#2}\or
    \efive@digits{#2}\fi
  \number#2%
}
\newcommand\etwo@digits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
}
\newcommand\ethree@digits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
}
\newcommand\efour@digits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
}
\newcommand\efive@digits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<10000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{tmpa}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tmpa}{5}
\epadzeroes{2}{\value{tmpa}}

\epadzeroes{3}{\value{tmpa}}

\setcounter{tmpa}{9999}
\epadzeroes{5}{\value{tmpa}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is crazy - I don't know why (I'll say I don't understand it really :( ). But it goes. How you get the zeros in front of the value? In a other case I need five digits.

Comment: I have all implementated and it goes well. Next time i will looking for the `@`. I don't know what it done. Thank you